# How to understand behavior of beamercolorbox with regard to width?

Tags: beamer

The manual of beamer 3.59 on page 125 reads as follows:

> If the width is larger than the normal text width, as specified by the
> value of  \textwidth, the width of the resulting box is reset to the
> width \textwidth,  but intelligent negative skips are inserted at the
> left and right end of the box.

I am trying to match this with the result of the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{bgcolor}{fg=black,bg=red}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\dimexpr\paperwidth+1.0cm\relax]{bgcolor}Boxborder\hfill redrobxoB\end{beamercolorbox}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
Paperwidth: \the\paperwidth

Textwidth: \the\textwidth
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**My problem:**

The wd of the colorbox is set to paperwidth+1.0cm and clearly larger than textwidth. However the width of the box does not get reset to the width of textwidth but fills even more than the paperwidth. It is reported as overfull and 28.45274pt too wide. But even if we deduct this overfull dimension from the paperwidth (as we can see visually, the box is at least as wide as the paperwidth), one still does not come anything near to the textwidth, which is a whopping 57pt smaller than the paperwidth.

Is there a bug in the documentation or in the implementation or in my understanding? And if the latter: What is the nature of the misunderstanding?